# How to create DataFrame in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file.

```
index  value    d F
0    975  25.35   5
1    976  26.28   4
2    977  26.24   1
3    978  25.76   0
4    979  26.08   0
```

I created a dataframe from CSV file this way.
df = pd.read_csv("ThisFileL.csv")

I want to reconstruct a new DataFrame in my way by coppying the 2nd Columns three times.

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
data.add(df.value)
data.add(df.value)
data.add(df.value)
```

But it didn't work out. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Your file content is not separated by `,`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `data['value1']=data['value']`, `data['value2']=data['value']`, etc? It should create new columns holding the numbers in `value`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by assigning 'value' column data in to new columns of the DataFrame.

```
df = pd.read_csv("ThisFileL.csv" , sep=' ')
df['value1'] = df.value
df['value2'] = df.value
```

The output of this would have following column headings.

```
index | value | d | F | value1 | value2
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new column in a DataFrame is pretty straightforward. `df[column_label] = values`

What you're going to have to do is come up with some good names for your columns. I'll use a, b and c in this example.

```
df = pd.read_csv("ThisFileL.csv")
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
    new_df[key] = df['value']
```